# C# Equivalent events in Java

Tags: c#, java, migration

I have developed a PC based API in **C#** to communicate with an embedded electronic device. This API reads the PC COM port, decodes packets, constructs packets and raises events. Now I need to develop the same API in Android mobile. As there are differences between C# and Java Events, I'm quite confused how to achieve the same in Java.

The following C# code rises events:

```
public class MARGserial
{

    dataObject = BT_DeconstructPacket(encodedPacket);
    if (dataObject != null) // if packet successfully deconstructed
    {
        OnMARGdataReceived(dataObject);

        if (dataObject is RawMARGdata)
        {
           OnRawMARGdataReceived((RawMARGdata)dataObject);

           PacketsReadCounter.RawMARGdataPackets++; 
        }
    }
    public delegate void onRawMARGdataReceived(object sender, RawMARGdata e);
    public event onRawMARGdataReceived RawMARGdataReceived;
    protected virtual void OnRawMARGdataReceived(RawMARGdata e)
    { 
       if (RawMARGdataReceived != null)
          RawMARGdataReceived(this, e);
    }

}/*End of MARGserial class */
```

The following code is for subscribing to Event `OnRawMARGdataReceived` in windows console application.

```
public static MARG_api.MARGserial MARGserial = new MARG_api.MARGserial("COM44");
MARGserial.RawMARGdataReceived += new MARG_api.MARGserial.onRawMARGdataReceived(MARGserial_RawMARGdataReceived);

static void MARGserial_RawMARGdataReceived(object sender, MARG_api.RawMARGdata e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Data :  " + e.Accelerometer[0].ToString() + "  "+e.Accelerometer[1].ToString()+ "  "+e.Accelerometer[2].ToString());
}
```

In case of Android Java application, Main Activity class in the application itself has to subscribe for events which are fired inside of another class thread ( this thread reads Bluetooth buffer & constructs packets)

Comment: Events are not a language feature in Java. This answer sums it up nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4763441/14357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully developed android application which can connect to my bluetooth device using the [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) sample provided by Google.  The bluetooth module of device has SPP (serial port profile) which is from [RovingNetworks (RN-41)](http://www.rovingnetworks.com/products/RN41).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a GUI-Toolkit like "Swing" then in Java the Listener Pattern is quite common for this kind of task.

That is you have a listener that registers itself at the host, which in turn holds a list of listeners. If the event corresponding to the listener happens, the listeners then get notified.

It is pretty similar to the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).

Maybe this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763225/java-listener-design-pattern-for-subscribing) is helpful.

Comment: It should be Swing not SWING.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Design Patterns here, notably Observer:

In Observer you have an interface called IObserver with a method called update() that you make all your interested objects implement. Then the master object stores a set of s and when something happens it calls .update() on every object in that collection (the callback in essence). This is common in MVC architectures too if you want to go that way for GUI, when the model state changes and the view needs to be updated.

You could also achieve Delegate style first order functions using the Command design pattern, which is very useful in Java given there is no native support for this concept.

I'm not sure if the above will help in your specific context, but Design Patterns are usually a good way to go and solve all manner of problems.

Comment: You mentioned the Command Pattern. The OP may find more info on that one here: http://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html (fyi)

Answer (score -1):

Please check out -

http://v-lad.org/projects/gnu.io.android/

Comment: How does this answer the question "C# Equivalent events in Java"?

Comment: sorry misinterpreted the question.